# Is there a better way to plot a graph of selected variables based on an equation or several equations?

Tags: plotting

I am new to Mathematica, and I have some questions regarding plotting.
For example, I have an equation from my physical model A^2-A=E^0.001t, and I would like to plot A vs t with t from 0 to 1000. I am currently using the Solve function to do this.

```
A[t_] := A /. Solve[A^2 - A - E^(-10^-3 t) == 0, A][[2]]
Plot[A[t], {t, 0, 1000}]
```

I know in my model A>1, so I ignore the root where A is less than 1. My question is :would there be better ways in Mathematica to do this instead of solving the equation and manually choosing the root I need? Could I directly plot A vs t with some requirements(A>1 and 0<t<1000).

More generally, if I have several functions f[x]=x^2+x; g[x]= x+E^x+x^3; h[x]=x+1/x, Can I plot f[x] vs g[x] or h[x] within some predefined range (for example 2<f[x]<100, 2<g[x]<10^4) without solving the equation first?

I was told that a software called Mathcad could directly draw A vs t or f[x] vs g[x] in my aforementioned examples. Could anyone tell me how to do this in Mathematica or is it possible to do this in Mathematica? Thanks!

Comment: `ContourPlot[A^2 - A - E^(-10^-3 t) == 0, {t, 0, 1000}, {A, 1, 2}]`

Comment: `f[x_] = x^2 + x;
g[x_] = x + E^x + x^3;
ParametricPlot[{x^2 + x, x + E^x + x^3}, {x, -5, 5}]`

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot! I didn't know ContourPlot and ParametricPlot before. This is what I was looking for!